# How do I use point in time with search after in ElasticSearch JAVA API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm trying to test pagination in the latest release (8.5) with point-in-time and search after in the Java API. I don't know exactly how to implement it as the Java API documentation is barely existent and the only reference being the elasticsearch one.
I've tried this:

```
public List<Offer> searchOffer(OfferRequest request) throws IOException {
        List<Offer> offers=new ArrayList<>();
        Query query = prepareSearchElasticQuery(request);

        PointInTimeReference.Builder pit=new PointInTimeReference.Builder();
        pit.keepAlive(new Time.Builder().time("1m").build());


        SearchResponse<Offer> response = elasticsearchClient.search(s -> s
                        .index("offers")
                        .pit(pit.build())
                        .searchAfter()
                        .size(1000)
                        .query(query)
                        .sort(new SortOptions.Builder().field(f>f.field("offerId").order(SortOrder.Asc))),
                Offer.class
        );
```

But I'm not sure if it's the correct way to build it, and also what argument should searchAfter() take.

**Edit**:
I ran a query on the first elements before the page I want and got the id of the last document. Then I passed it to the searchAfter method:

```
SearchResponse<Offer> response = elasticsearchClient.search(s -> s
                        .index("offers")
                        .size(PAGE_SIZE)
                        .searchAfter(sa->sa.stringValue(searchAfterId))
                        .query(query)
                        .sort(new SortOptions.Builder()
                                .field(f-> f.field("offerId").order(SortOrder.Asc))
                                .build())
                ,Offer.class
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The searchAfter receive list parameters from your Sort. I see you use "offerId" to sort results, so you must put inside searchAfter the last value sort of response hits.